# Foreach only showing the last row

Tags: php, xml, foreach, substr

I'd like to print a movies' box office with "UP", "DOWN", "NEW", "-" for showing the evolution of each movie's rank. So that's why I created a condition interpreting the rank evolution (under the aspect of a number positive or negative). Nevertheless, I only manage to print the last movie's informations.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($fichier);
foreach ($xml->weeklyBoxOfficeList->weeklyBoxOffice as $film)
    echo "
    <tr>
      <td class='rank'>{$film->rank}</td>
      <td class='rank-evo'>"; 
      if(substr($film->rankInten,0,1) == '-') 
        echo "<img src='_img/down.png'/>$film->rankInten"; 
      elseif(substr($film->rankInten,0,1) == 0 and $film->rankOldAndNew == 'OLD') 
        echo "<img src='_img/old.png'/>"; 
      elseif(substr($film->rankInten,0,1) == 0 and $film->rankOldAndNew == 'NEW') 
        echo "<img src='_img/new.png'/>"; 
      else 
        echo "<img src='_img/up.png'/>$film->rankInten"; 
      echo "</td> 
      <td>{$film->movieNm}</td>
    </tr>";
?>
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong? Thank you

Comment: could you print_r($xml) before the beginning of the loop just so we can see what's loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to enclose the loop with braces -

```
foreach ($xml->weeklyBoxOfficeList->weeklyBoxOffice as $film) { // <- this
    echo "...";
    ...
    echo "</td> 
    <td>{$film->movieNm}</td>
    </tr>";
} // <-
```